# Python Web Scraping - How to download embedded Google drive pdf

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib

I'm trying to write a python script that downloads pdf files embedded (with an iframe tag) in a webpage. As long as the pdf file is directly embedded, `urllib` gets the job done easily.

However, I do not know what to do when the iframe tag contains a link to a Google Drive preview, like this

```
<iframe src='https://drive.google.com/file/d/3973056397343z/preview'></iframe>
```

Is there a way to deal with this case? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could parse links you want with regex for example and then do requests against them.

Comment: What do you mean do requests against them? How does that work? Sorry, I am rather new to web scraping.